# argparse not taking default option

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me why the default option is being taken below?

#### Code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='SCRIPT')
parser.add_argument('-fe','--force_edl',action='store',dest='force_edl',choices=['True', 'False'], default = False,help='<Required> Enable EDL loading by default..',required=False)
global force_edl
results = parser.parse_args()

if results.force_edl:
    force_edl = results.force_edl
print "force_edl"
print force_edl
```

#### Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "defaultparse.py", line 10, in
>
> print force_edl
>
> NameError: global name 'force_edl' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if results.force_edl:
    force_edl = results.force_edl
```

The reason why the assignment inside the above `if` doesn't take place is because:

```
>>> results
Namespace(force_edl=False)
>>> results.force_edl
False
```

`results.force_edl` is a `boolean` with the value `False`. What you instead need to be doing is:

```
if 'force_edl' in results:
    force_edl = results.force_edl
```

Or, since you already know that `results` will always have `force_dl`, just assign directly:

```
force_edl = results.force_edl
```

Comment: Nehal - how do I strip the `force_edl `value .I tried `force_edl = results.force_edl.strip()` but it throws an error

Comment: `boolean` values can't be stripped.

Answer (score 0):

`results.force_edl` will always be `False`. You're updating the global variable after conditional checking, which will never be executed. And the global `force_edl` will still be undefined since you didn't assign any value to it when you declared.

Do something like the following:

```
global force_edl = False
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred because the variable force_edl was just "**DECLARED**" but not "**DEFINED**" with some value.

It gets assigned in your `if` block only but that `if` block won't execute since the value by default will be a false value and hence you get this error.

> You must assign it some value before you use it.